# What does MATLAB's bitxor function do?

Tags: matlab

I've tried it with numbers, and it seems that it produces either the absolute value of the sum of two numbers or the absolute value of the difference. But I'm not able to figure out a general rule. I read the description on Mathworks, but it's not helpful. Here are some examples:

```
>> bitxor(1,1:10)
ans =    
     0     3     2     5     4     7     6     9     8    11

>> bitxor(2,1:10)
ans =
     3     0     1     6     7     4     5    10    11     8

>> bitxor(3,1:10)
ans =
     2     1     0     7     6     5     4    11    10     9

>> bitxor(4,1:10)
ans =
     5     6     7     0     1     2     3    12    13    14
```

Comment: can you share some examples? I would guess that it does a XOR operation on the number bits (integers only I assume).

Comment: Try google... It does a bitwise xor between 2 numbers e.g. 0110 xor 1011 = 1101. (in binary notation)

Comment: is a xor like a "sum"?

Comment: Essentially, for each bit of a number, if they are equal return 0 otherwise return 1. I.e. 1xor1=0, 1xor0=1, 0xor0=0, do this for each bit pair of the numbers to get the result. So 5xor3 = 6 because 101xor011=110.

Comment: The MathWorks documentation on `bitxor` is quite clear on the function and its use. I'm not sure why you didn't find it helpful. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitxor.html

Comment: @mathemagician FWIW, `xor` is essentially a sum with no carry.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to see what bitxor does if you represent your integers in binary format. Then for each bit position, the **xor** operation returns 1 if both digits are different, and 0 if they're the same.

To demonstrate, we'll use the following (ugly) `binarize` function that takes an array of integers and returns the binary (4-bit, to be exact) string representation for each integer, and formats them as a horizontal string 'array' with spaces in between each 4-bit string. This will enable us to visually compare two 4-bit inputs and their xor output bit-by-bit.

```
binarize = @(x) reshape([dec2bin(x,4)'; repmat(' ',1,size(dec2bin(x)',2))],1,[]);
```

then

```
>> [binarize(1:10);                % first input : integers from 1 to 10
    binarize(ones(1,10));          % second input: an array of ten '1's.
    binarize(bitxor(1, 1:10))]     % the xor operation between the two

ans =

0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 1010 
0001 0001 0001 0001 0001 0001 0001 0001 0001 0001 
0000 0011 0010 0101 0100 0111 0110 1001 1000 1011
```

Confirm that for each digit in the lower row, you have a 1 if the two digits above it are different, and 0 otherwise; and also that the last row corresponds to the 4-bit representation for the integers [0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8, 11] as in your example.